# Is there a way to search SQL database for similar words (mean not identical words)?

Tags: c#, java, php, mysql

Is there a way to search MySQL database for similar words (mean not identical words) . For example : user searches in database for word "abcd" and there is a word "abd" in the database so the search engine or the program Ask the user "Do you mean [abd] ? " as in most of search engines in the web ? Please notice that the search word is not a part of the existing word (can't use "like")

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at the [Damerau-Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance) algorithm.  It calculates the "distance" between two strings and determines how many steps it takes to transform one string into another.  The less steps the closer the two strings are.

[This](http://codejanitor.com/wp/2007/02/10/levenshtein-distance-as-a-mysql-stored-function/) article shows the algorithm implemented as a MySQL stored function.

The algorithm is so much better than LIKE or SOUNDEX.

I believe Google uses crowd sourced data rather than an algorithm.  ie if a user types in abcd, clicks on the back button and then immediately searches for abd then it establishes a relationship between the two search terms as the user wasn't happy with the results.  Once you have a very large community searching then the pattern appears.

Answer (score 2):

Since the link in Dave Barker's answer is dead, here is the code from [an archived version of the website](https://web.archive.org/web/20100404151800/http://codejanitor.com/wp/2007/02/10/levenshtein-distance-as-a-mysql-stored-function):

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION LEVENSHTEIN (s1 VARCHAR(255), s2 VARCHAR(255))
>   RETURNS INT
>     DETERMINISTIC
>       BEGIN
>         DECLARE s1_len, s2_len, i, j, c, c_temp, cost INT;
>         DECLARE s1_char CHAR;
>         DECLARE cv0, cv1 VARBINARY(256);
>         SET s1_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s1), s2_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s2), cv1 = 0x00, j = 1, i = 1, c = 0;
>         IF s1 = s2 THEN
>           RETURN 0;
>         ELSEIF s1_len = 0 THEN
>           RETURN s2_len;
>         ELSEIF s2_len = 0 THEN
>           RETURN s1_len;
>         ELSE
>           WHILE j <= s2_len DO
>             SET cv1 = CONCAT(cv1, UNHEX(HEX(j))), j = j + 1;
>           END WHILE;
>           WHILE i <= s1_len DO
>             SET s1_char = SUBSTRING(s1, i, 1), c = i, cv0 = UNHEX(HEX(i)), j = 1;
>             WHILE j <= s2_len DO
>                 SET c = c + 1;
>                 IF s1_char = SUBSTRING(s2, j, 1) THEN SET cost = 0; ELSE SET cost = 1; END IF;
>                 SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j, 1)), 16, 10) + cost;
>                 IF c > c_temp THEN SET c = c_temp; END IF;
>                 SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j+1, 1)), 16, 10) + 1;
>                 IF c > c_temp THEN SET c = c_temp; END IF;
>                 SET cv0 = CONCAT(cv0, UNHEX(HEX(c))), j = j + 1;
>             END WHILE;
>             SET cv1 = cv0, i = i + 1;
>           END WHILE;
>         END IF;
>         RETURN c;
>       END
> ```
>
> To note:
>
> - Maximum length of input strings is 255 characters. I’m sure you could edit the function to support more if needed.
> - I’ve tested it with international characters on a utf8_bin column and it seemed to work, but I’ve not tested that capability exstensively.
> - I’ve only tested it on MySQL 5.0+. No idea how it will work on versions less than that.
>
> And as a bonus I also created a helper function that returns the ratio
>   (as a percentage) of different : same characters which can be more
>   helpful than just a straight edit distance (idea from here).
>
> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION LEVENSHTEIN_RATIO (s1 VARCHAR(255), s2 VARCHAR(255))
>   RETURNS INT
>     DETERMINISTIC
>       BEGIN
>         DECLARE s1_len, s2_len, max_len INT;
>         SET s1_len = LENGTH(s1), s2_len = LENGTH(s2);
>         IF s1_len > s2_len THEN SET max_len = s1_len; ELSE SET max_len = s2_len; END IF;
>         RETURN ROUND((1 - LEVENSHTEIN(s1, s2) / max_len) * 100);
>       END
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how far apart they are, you could look into soundex perhaps..

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Levenshtein_distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Answer (score 0):

Another technique is to create indexes on [trigrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigram).